# Can't serialize with Jackson Json class fields if it extends ArrayList

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson Json. I can't serialize class fields if class extends ArrayList.

Class:

```
public class DataElement {
    private Date date;
    private int val1;
    private int val2;
    // constructor, getters, setters
}

public class DataArray extends ArrayList<DataElement> {
    private String info;
    private int num;
    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Serialization:

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
jsonMapper.writeValue(new File("path"), dataArray);
```

Result file contains DataElements only:

```
[ {
  "date" : 1446405540000,
  "val1" : 10296,
  "val2" : 30365
}, {
  "date" : 1446405600000,
  "val1" : 40164,
  "val2" : 20222
} ]
```

'num' and 'info' are not saved into file.

How to save full class including its fields?

Comment: How would this look to you in JSON? It's impossible to represent, putting two arbitrary key/value pairs into a JSON array (which is what an ArrayList is in JSON). Don't extend ArrayList and just include an ArrayList as a field in the class.

Comment: @peeskillet, ArrayList may be wrapped somehow, for example:
`{
 "num": "123",
 "info": "information",
 "ArrayList":
  [{
   "date" : 1446405540000,
   "val1" : 10296,
   "val2" : 30365
  }, {
   "date" : 1446405600000,
   "val1" : 40164,
   "val2" : 20222
  }]
}`

There are annotations in Jackson Json, but I can't get from them the requested result.

Comment: Then is it no longer a JSON array, but a JSON object, in which case, personally I would prefer composition over inheritance. That's just me. I don't know maybe you have a requirement to keep the inheritance. But anyway it looks like @ManosNikolaidis has your solution below.

Comment: @peeskillet I would also prefer composition in this case.

Comment: Ok, I will try to convert to composition. @ManosNikolaidis, thank you for the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Jackson will serialize your POJOs according to the `JsonFormat.Shape`. For an `ArrayList` object that is `ARRAY`. You can change the shape to `OBJECT` with an annotation.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public class DataArray extends ArrayList<DataElement> {
```

Make sure `DataArray` has a getter that returns an `ArrayList` for e.g.

```
public ArrayList<DataElement> getContents() {
    return new ArrayList<>(this);
}
```

When I tried the above code I saw this field at the resulting JSON

```
"empty":false
```

You can use `@JsonIgnore` to prevent that from appearing